# Google Data Highlighter | Missing Tags

Tags: google-search-console, structured-data

I'm using Google Data Highlighter for the first time and I'm not sure what I'm doing.

I have a one page bootstrap/jquery/html product page that gives all the specs on a specific kitchen appliance.

When I go to the data highlighter, the entire site is grayed out. One image shows from the slider but no other images or data are shown except for the nav bar. Because of this, it won't allow me to highlight anything on the site.

It says there are missing tags, obviously, and when I go to "add missing tags", I am able to add tags and save, but when I click "Done", each time it tell me I still have missing tags.

When I continue on to "create page set", I can't do anything because I get this:
"Pattern does not match any additional pages. If you would like to create a single page source, please restart."